# PHP: is there a way to convert a private ECDSA key to its corresponding public key?

Tags: php

As described here (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses) I am trying to convert a private ECDSA key to its corresponding public key. (See step1 and step2).

I think I need some code which multiplies some coordinates on the elliptic curve. But I dont know how. Can someone help me, please?

// Unfortunately, this answer doesn't help me enough since I don't understand how to use the code. Can someone clearify that or give alternative solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you do "need some code which multiplies some coordinates on the elliptic curve" :). If you don't have extensive cryptography experience I would recommend you use library rather than trying to implement details yourself.

Googling I've found [Bitcoin-lib-php](https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-lib-php). Looking at  [the code it seems it seems this function](https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-lib-php/blob/master/src/BitcoinLib.php#L506) does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I am not able to get this code running. I dont have classes in my php but the code you suggested does need classes and a lot of other stuff (composer ...). Is there a solution which is a bit easier? I am not able to implement this due to lack of programming skills .... :/

Answer (score 0):

I created a small PHP library. You can do that using [this class](https://github.com/ItayRosen/cryptophp/blob/master/src/secp256k1.php)

You can use it like this:

```
require('secp256k1.php');
$Secp256k1 = new Secp256k1();

$public_key = $Secp256k1 -> private2public($private_key);
```